# Performing the same two calculations on some sheets in my workbook

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

The worksheets contain tables of different row length

I'm trying to perform two calculations on a table to work out averages. Then do the same calculations in each sheet in my workbook. There are 'x' number of sheets. The tables in each sheet are dynamic in length. There's errors in this code that I'm trying to resolve

```
Sub CalcOnSheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim row As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ActiveWorksheet As Long
Dim ThisWorksheet As Long
Dim n As Integer

Dim x As Integer
x = Sheets.Count

 For n = 3 To x


Sheets(n).range("I2:Q" & lastRow + 3).Columns.AutoFit
Sheets(n).range("D2:D" & lastRow + 3).ColumnWidth = 15


lastRow = Sheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
If lastRow > 1 Then

 For row = 2 To lastRow


Sheets(n).range("B1:P" & lastRow + 3).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00_); 
(£#,##0.00)"
Sheets(n).range("I1:I" & lastRow + 3).NumberFormat = "#,##0_);(#,##0)"
Sheets(n).range("Q1:Q" & lastRow + 3).NumberFormat = "#0.0%_);(#0.0%)"

If Sheets(n).Cells(row, 4).Value <> "" Then
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 16).Value = Sheets(n).Cells(row, 10).Value - 
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 11).Value - _
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 12).Value - Sheets(n).Cells(row, 13).Value - 
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 14).Value - Sheets(n).Cells(row, 15).Value
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 17).Value = Sheets(n).Cells(row, 16).Value / 
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 10).Value

End If
Next

Dim r As range, j As Long, k As Long, z As Long
j = Sheets(n).range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

'This adds up the totals on the sheet
'changing the first value of k stops it adding up un-needed columns
For k = 9 To j
Set r = Sheets(n).range(Sheets(n).Cells(1, k), Sheets(n).Cells(1, 
k).End(xlDown))
r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
r.End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
Next k

'This deletes the total of the profit margins which is meaningless
Sheets(n).range("Q" & lastRow).Offset(2) = ""


'This changes the format of column I average value back to two decimal places
Sheets(n).range("I" & lastRow).Offset(3).NumberFormat = "0.00_);(0.00)"

'Calculation 1   This calculates Average profit per unit
Sheets(n).range("B" & lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheets(n).range("P" & 
lastRow).Offset(2).Value / Sheets(n).range("I" & lastRow).Offset(2).Value


'Calculation 2    This calculates Average profit per order
Sheets(n).range("A" & lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheets(n).range("P" & 
lastRow).Offset(2).Value / Rows("D").Column.Count



Else

MsgBox ("There is no data at column D")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to know what line and what error (?)

Comment: Error is on line beginning Sheets(n).range("A" .... and the error is Runtime error 1004, Application-defined or Object-defined error

Comment: For starters I do not see that x has a value in the code that you have posted.

Comment: Where and how did your code calculate `lastRow` and `x`? `x` could be `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`. And `lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(XlUp).row`. Supposing that all columns have the same number of rows like A:A.

Comment: Try.   x = Worksheets.Count

Comment: What is this all about `/row("D").Column.Count`?

Comment: @SJR I'm trying to count the number of transactions in a table (excluding the header) so I can perform the division to find the mean average. I've been using column D Column D as my number of rows. Clumsy I know but I'm new to this and finding my way around

Comment: You firstly try to AutoFit ranges using `lastRow` but the code calculates it after...

Comment: I do not see the line starting with what you say, returning the error... Isn't it `Sheets(n).range("I2:Q" & lastRow + 3).Columns.AutoFit`?

Comment: The whole syntax is wrong. (1) You can't begin a line with / (2) "D" is a column not a row (3) It should be `columns.count` (but D is only one column).

Comment: @FaneDuru The error is on this line    Sheets(n).range("A" & lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheets(n).range("P" & lastRow).Offset(2).Value / Sheets(n).range("D" & Rows.Count)  When I blank that line out the program runs on the remaining averahe calculation without errors but it returns incorrect values because I'm not sure about the last section of the line (after the divide sign). I want the value to be the bumber of rows on the table apart from the header but not sure of the syntax

Comment: If the range is empty, an error accurs. Try moving the cursor over variables and see what it shows...

Comment: I may be able to work part of the problem if I knew the correct syntax for counting the number of columnsin my table excluding the Row 1 and the TOTal and Average rows at the bottom. There are no empty cells